# List initialization of static member of template class

Tags: c++, templates, static-variables

I am getting a syntax error with VS2015 when I try to initialize static member variables like this:

```
template<typename T> class Foo { public: static const T bar; };

template<typename T> const T Foo<T>::bar{ T(1) };
```

On the other hand the following works:

```
template<typename T> const T Foo<T>::bar = T(1);
```

What is wrong here? Is it the compiler or does C++ not allow list initialization in this case?

Comment: Compile with both clang and gcc [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7a6aaedb1894c23). So mostly a msvc bug.

Comment: @Jarod42 why am I not surprised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a MSVS2015 compiler bug.

Comment: I couldn't find a bug on Connect for this issue so I created one (as I've just come across it in my own code): https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3075055